# unable to get sendKeyEvent method in appium-android

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, appium

In my appium-code, on using swipe, scroll methods and executing the code. Getting the below exception.

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

And I don't see the `SendKeyEvent` method in the auto suggest dropdown. When I am manually typing SendKeyEvent(), it's throwing an error as undefined in the type AndroidDriver.

Attached screenshot [image: SendKeyEvent method unavilable]

Can anyone let me know please ?

Comment: What is the Java Client version you are using?

Comment: Latest java client 3.2.0

Answer (score 4):

If you use java client 3.2.0 then you should try using pressKeyCode(keyCode) method instead of sendKeyEvent(keyEvent). 
Hope it helps.

Comment: Worked on client 3.4.1.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, because this method is not for the driver. You can send keys to the element, not the driver. The solution would be following:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("the_id"));
element.sendKeys("necessary_text");
```

Comment: Of course that you can send keys to the driver. It depends how you declared the driver before, but the method then is slightly different: driver.sendKeyEvent(66);

Comment: Wrong. It is not supported by `AppiumDriver` class (Selenium v2.47.1 & Appium 3.2.0.).

Answer (score -2):

This code worked for me:

```
AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
driver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.HOME);
```

What is supported? What is obsolete? How to find answer to these questions?
Can someone please direct to reference???